# how to use transition in multiview between view changes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using a multiview with more than three views , i want to use transition when a change, one gone and other come .
how can i do this thing ?

```
<asp:MultiView runat="server">
        <asp:View ID ="view_first" runat="server">

        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="view_second" runat="server">

        </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
```

Comment: What do you mean by transition? Like an animation or some sorts? Or do you just want to [switch the active view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.multiview.setactiveview(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Yes i want like a animation

Comment: You're going to want to look into JavaScript for accomplishing that. jQuery will help with all kinds of [animations](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and jQuery UI has built in effects for [hiding and showing things](http://jqueryui.com/effect/).